# Functional programming in R : illustration with vandermonde matrix

Tags: r, functional-programming, higher-order-functions

I would like to get a feel of functional programming in R.
To that effect, I would like to write the [vandermonde matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix) computation, as it can involve a few constructs.

In imperative style that would be :

```
vandermonde.direct <- function (alpha, n) 
{
  if (!is.vector(alpha))  stop("argument alpha is not a vector")
  if (!is.numeric(alpha)) stop("argument n is not a numeric vector")
  m <- length(alpha)
  V <- matrix(0, nrow = m, ncol = n)
  V[, 1] <- rep(1, m)
  j <- 2
  while (j <= n) {
    V[, j] <- alpha^(j - 1)
    j <- j + 1
  }
  return(V)
}
```

How would you write that elegantly in R in functional style ?

The following does not work :

```
x10 <- runif(10)
n <- 3
Reduce(cbind, aaply(seq_len(n-1),1, function (i) { function (x) {x**i}}), matrix(1,length(x10),1))
```

As it tells me `Error: Results must have one or more dimensions.` for list of function which go from `i in seq_len(3-1)` to the function `x -> x**i.`

Comment: I would use `outer( x10, seq(0,n-1), "^" )`.

Comment: domo arigato... do you have any document targetting specifically FP + R ?

Comment: I guess that could be a good one https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/Functional-programming

Comment: there's this wiki of @hadley https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/Functional-programming

Comment: @VincentZoonekynd Consider making that an answer?

Comment: @Roland it is certainly perfect for VDM but reduce, cbind, maps are more general than exterior product which begets a specific structure.

Comment: @nicolas I chose to focus on the specifics of your question, instead of the extremely broad topic of functional programming. The letter would make this a candidate for closing.

Comment: @Roland my question is not about the extremely broad subject of functional programming *either*

Comment: @Roland changed the title to make it clearer : the specific example of VDM matrix, used as an illustration for FP.

Comment: It's still not clear to me what you expect as an answer. Less optimal solutions using `*apply` loops? SO is for specific coding problems. From your comments it doesn't seem like your question fits this scope.

Comment: @Roland the problem is the one expressed, not more, not less : express vdm matrix using higher order functions. which part is not specific to you, vdm or functional ?

Comment: Then why did you argue against `outer` as an answer? This whole discussion is pretty pointless, so let's end it.

Comment: because, again, it was not the question. have a good day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not seem very natural to use `Reduce` for this task.
The error message is caused by `aaply`, which tries to return an array:
you can use `alply` instead; you also need to call your functions, somewhere.

Here are a few idiomatic alternatives:

```
outer( x10, 0:n, `^` )
t(sapply( x10, function(u) u^(0:n) ))
sapply( 0:3, function(k) x10^k )
```

Answer (score 2):

Here it is with `Reduce`:

```
m <- as.data.frame(Reduce(f=function(left, right) left * x10, 
                          x=1:(n-1), init=rep(1,length(x10)), accumulate=TRUE))
names(m) <- 1:n - 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option, that uses the environment features of R:

```
vdm <- function(a)
{
    function(i, j) a[i]^(j-1)
}
```

This will work for arbitrary `n` (the number of columns).

To create the "Vandermonde functional" for a given `a`, use this:

```
v <- vdm(a=c(10,100))
```

To build a matrix all at once, use this:

```
> outer(1:3, 1:4, v)
     [,1] [,2]  [,3]  [,4]
[1,]    1   10   100 1e+03
[2,]    1  100 10000 1e+06
[3,]    1   NA    NA    NA
```

Note that index `a[3]` is out of bounds, thus returning `NA` (except for the first column, which is `1`).